# Is it possible to snoop and read the websocket data traffic in iOS?

Tags: ios, websocket, snoop

is it possible of any other App on iOS be able to snoop the websocket traffic between app (i.e UIWebView based client ) with its background websocket server thread ? Note: All these apps and services are running locally on the same iOS device.

Comment: You mean like Fiddler/Wireshark can do in Windows?

Comment: And related query will the sandboxing security mechanism in the iOS prevent other app from snooping the websocket traffic that is between two apps running localling in iOS device

Comment: @Renan I think he means, if he has a backgrounded app running the Websocket server, can any app on the device connect to it and snoop the traffic.

Comment: >>You mean like Fiddler/Wireshark can do in Windows? yes...but on non-rooted iOS device.    agree with Benoit's response too.